# Where is console log error (index):1 pointing to?

Tags: wordpress, console

How do you find the source of a console log error?

The error message is:

> was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The source is (index):1.

There were multiple sources that I have fixed but it is still displaying as index:1. Index 1 just points to: !DOCTYPE html.

I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the source is (index):1 most of the time that means that it is directly in your document HTML. Based on the error u're pasted i would look into the head part of the website and look for googleapi font inclusion